# Salesforce Communities - Multiple URls

Tags: community, customer-community, url

Is there a way to setup Salesforce communities to reflect multiple URLs?  We want to let each region have their own community but all of the communities will essentially be identical but want their own 'custom' URL and/or landing page? If this is able to be done, any limits on # of URLs?  And what is the best, cleanest way to set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create custom domains and have them redirect to the community - see [help article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000212707&type=1) on domain setup. This feature only works in production instances though it can be setup in a sandbox it will not be functional.

With the landing page it would be possible to have each community with a separate one whether you use Visualforce and tabs or a templated community such as Customer Service (Napili).

In a templated community such as Napili you can use [page variations](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_page_visibilty_overview.htm&type=0) to show different audiences a different version of a page, including location based (IP addresses).

As you have separate communities the redirects would not be an issue and it is unlikely you will need more than the standard 100 communities available.

> You can have up to 100 communities in your Salesforce org. Active, inactive, and preview communities, including Force.com sites, count against this limit.
>   To see this limit in your org, from Setup enter Communities in the Quick Find box, then select All Communities. The Maximum number of communities field displays 100.

From [help](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=limits_communities_max_number_of_communities.htm&type=0)

Comment: would each custom url be a separate community?  They would all be same setup but separate urls per region/branch

Comment: Do you need one single community as there are possibilities with that or separate communities with the same build?

Comment: It would be all one community but our regions want to have a custom url that appears to be just for their area basically so we can put it in their signature or they can use it and the customer thinks they are going specifically that region only.

Comment: I think that is still possible but I need to try and see if it would work. It would be possible to still have different landing pages using a lightning community with page variations based on audiences.

Comment: yes because I think we would hit the 100 limit quickly

Comment: Also is there a limit to landing pages for communities?

Comment: I can't find a limit on the number of page variations allowed with a lightning community, but I know there will be one.

Comment: so use landing pages with custom URLs to take everyone to the same Lightning community, correct?  I would just need to verify limits.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.